# Is there an R function that can replace data that contains certain characters?

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

What I have is something like this:

| Contact | ID Number |
| --- | --- |
| Me@email | 576489 |
| You@memail | 984601 |
| 072233498 | 256470 |
| @email | --- |

I want to replace it so that anything containing an @ or a number is replaced entirely with simply "Yes" is that possible? So it would output something like this:

| Contact | ID Number |
| --- | --- |
| Yes | Yes |
| Yes | Yes |
| Yes | Yes |
| Yes | --- |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```r
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(grepl("@|\\d", x), "Yes", x))

df
#>   Contact ID Number
#> 1     Yes       Yes
#> 2     Yes       Yes
#> 3     Yes       Yes
#> 4     Yes       ---
```

---

**Reproducible data**

```r
df <-  structure(list(Contact = c("Me@email", "You@memail", "072233498", 
"@email"), `ID Number` = c("576489", "984601", "256470", "---"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df
#>      Contact ID Number
#> 1   Me@email    576489
#> 2 You@memail    984601
#> 3  072233498    256470
#> 4     @email       ---
```

Answer (score 0):

str_replace(string, pattern, replacement) from the package "stringr"

```
str_replace(string, "@", "Yes")
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think I phrased that poorly, that just replaced "@" symbol "Yes", becoming MeYesemail. I need to replace anything that contains "@" with "Yes", from "Me@email" to "Yes", just from it having the "@" symbol.